# Fourier Transform of Spin operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, fourier-transform, many-body, spin-models

Fourier Transform is often used to diagonalize an infinte or periodic lattice Hamiltonian, for example in the tight-binding model
$$
\begin{aligned}H=t\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}c_{i}^{\dagger}c_{j}\end{aligned}
$$
we may use the Fourier Transform on the creation and annilation operators
$$
\begin{aligned}c_{\mathbf{x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x}}c_{\mathbf{k}},\quad c_{\mathbf{x}}^{\dagger}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x}}c_{\mathbf{k}}^{\dagger}\end{aligned}
$$
This is due to the **lattice translational symmetry** of the proboem, usually this greatly simplifies our problem.

I want to know if there is a similar transformation for spin operators, more specifically, suppose I have a Heisenberg Hamiltonian,
$$
\mathcal{H}=J\sum_{\langle ij\rangle}\mathbf{S}_{i}\cdot\mathbf{S}_{j}
$$
on a 2D square lattice, for example. And $S=1/2$ so we are talking about spin-1/2 particles.
Is there a way to make a transformation which looks like
$$
\mathbf{S}_{\mathbf{x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x}}\mathbf{S}_{\mathbf{k}}
$$
which would similarly greatly simplify our problem?

From my knowledge, Heisenberg model is probably not analytically solvable in 2D, so this method probably doesn't work for some reason. I just don't see intuitively why this would not work, given that the Heisenberg model described above do have lattice translation symmetry. Can anyone provide a reason why this won't work?

Another way to ask this question would be, can we find some "Crystal Momentum" operator that commute with our Hamiltonian and has eigenvalues $\mathbf{k}$? This would also greatly simplify our model, right?

Comment: The catch is that whereas that sum of fermionic operators still satisfies the canonical (anti)commutation relations, a sum of spin operators does not satisfy the Pauli algebra. Instead, in spin systems we typically appeal to, e.g., Clifford transformations (including the Kramers-Wannier transformation) which preserves the nice algebraic properties of spin operators.

Comment: I don't believe there is an equivalent Fourier transform for the spin operator as there is for fermionic creation/annihilation operators. However, one can utilize the [Jordan-Wigner transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Wigner_transformation) to convert spins into fermions. You can find an example of this transformation in the following paper on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0101188.pdf).